# Group policy redirection of 'recent items' to network share

Tags: group-policy, folder-redirection

Was tasked with finding a way to redirect a user's recent items to \[network share]\recent.

Server 2008 GPME: User Configuration-Windows Settings-Folder Redirection doesn't have recent items as an option.

1. Can this be done?
2. Assuming only through scripting?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by redirecting the whole AppData folder.
if you need the recent items only, then through scripting or a 3rd party software as far as i'm concerned.

Comment: Unfortunately appData isnt an option, which it was.  Just seems it has potential to cause app issues that my boss it not willing to take.  So for this, I suppose a logoff batch script would work best?